# jQuery Validate same name in inputs

Tags: jquery, validation, field

This form has inputs with the same name but similar (incremental) ids.

The form should validate if there is a name on person, the age must be mandatory..

Now only the first input is mandatory.

Here is my code:

```
    <form id="people">
        <div class="section">
            <input id="person1" name="person" class="person" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input id="age1" name="age" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <input id="person2" name="person" class="person" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input id="age2" name="age" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <input id="person3" name="person" class="person" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input id="age3" name="age" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
        ...
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#people').validate();
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                $('[id^="person"]').each(function(){
                    if ($(this).val().length>0){
                        //alert($(this).val());
                        //alert($(this).parent().find('.age').val());
                        $(this).rules('add', {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2,
                            messages: {
                                required: "Specify the person name",
                                minlength: "Minimum of 2 characters"
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).parent().find('.age').rules('add', {
                            required: true,
                            number: true,
                            messages: {
                                required: "Must have an age",
                                number: "Specify a valid age"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this 100 percent of the way there, but I think there are a couple of issues.. One is that using the submit click as the trigger may be interfering with the separate call to validate the form (i.e. validating twice) and the second is that inputs do not have unique names.

UPDATED:

```
   <form id="people" method="post">
        <div class="section">
            <input id="person1" name="person1" class="person" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input id="age1" name="age1" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <input id="person2" name="person2" class="person" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input id="age2" name="age2" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <input id="person3" name="person3" class="person" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input id="age3" name="age3" class="age" type="text" placeholder="Age" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>


$(function() {
    $('#people').validate();

    $('.person').blur(function() {

        if ($(this).val().length) {

            //alert($(this).val());
            //alert($(this).parent().find('.age').val());
            $(this).rules('add', {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                messages: {
                    required: "Specify the person name",
                    minlength: "Minimum of 2 characters"
                }
            });

            $(this).next('input').rules('add', {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Must have an age",
                    number: "Specify a valid age"
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it just validate the first 'row', do you know any other solution?

Comment: @Frarncisco I missed this the first time, but you need to have unique `name=` attributes on each of your input fields. Give my updated code a shot.

Comment: well, that is the main issue here, because I must have the same name attributes..

Comment: having the same name works with radio inputs (since they are mutually exclusive), but your form object relies on the name attributes, so they should be unique.